# E-net Deep learning architecture

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, max-pooling

The research paper is available on the link:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02147.pdf

Not able to understand the initial block of the Enet architecture.

Statement given in research paper on page 3:

ENet initial block. MaxPooling is performed with non-overlapping 2 × 2 windows,
and the convolution has 13 filters, which sums up to 16 feature maps after concatenation.
[image: initial block of e-net]

So the question is, How are we getting the 16 filters after concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example, suppose input image has dims as `(128,128,3)`, now with conv of `((3,3),2,13)`,where `2` is stride size and `13` is number of filter,  we get output as `(64,64,13)` (Basic conv operation). Now in the right block, we have `max-pool`, which return output as `(64,64,3)`. On `concat` both output, we have `(64,64,16)`.

Comment: After conv we get 13 feature maps of 64x64 and after max pooling on input image we get a single image. Then, how are channels (3) added with no. of feature maps (13)?

Comment: `13` represent channel output of conv layer, which concatenate with `3` channel of max-pool layer,.